# pca for multivariate time series - interpretation

Tags: time-series, pca, seasonality

I have a multivariate dataset where I did a PCA transformation and plotted the scores for my four principal components as a time-series in hope to observe some time-dependent trends for the data. 
I find the plots useful, but I have some troubles with interpretation.

[image]

My questions are:

1. **Is there a name and exemplary procedure for doing PCA on multivariate time series?**
   There was a similar questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158281/can-pca-be-applied-for-time-series-data) however the answers do not seem to go into the right direction.
   I stumpled upon dynamic PCA but it seems to define rather an on-line analysis.
2. To best of my knowledge - PCA does not take assumptions, so I have some potentially dependent variables in the analysis as well. **If a set of  variables has a high loading (either positive or negative) on a certain principal component can I conclude that they have a high (pos, neg) temporal correlation or dependence?**
3. **I guess from there it would make sense to go towards analysis seasonal decomposition, is there maybe a joint procedure reducing the number of steps?**
4. **If the assumption from question 2 holds (correlation) how do I interpret loadings which appear on each components in a similar trend vs those which change from PC to PC.** 
   E.g. var1 and var2 have similar positive loadings on PC1 and PC2, while var3 has a similar loading to var1,2 on PC1 and negative loading on PC2.

Thanks for any help!